# Does peek() on an already "EOF"ed ifstream continue to return EOF?

Tags: c++

Simple code:

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt");
std::string line;
while(getline(file,line))
  ; //exhaust file

//in this sample code, for simplicity assert that the only possible "fail"
//is EOF (which it will always be under normal circumstances).
assert(!file.fail() || file.eof());

assert(file.peek() == EOF); //does this always hold?
```

Will the final assert always succeed?

Question rephrased: Does the location after EOF also return EOF?

The documentation doesn't clearly mention what peek() does when the stream is ALREADY AT EOF, so hence my question.

Comment: I can't find/quote a specific section of a specification, but it would be rather stupid if it didn't work that way [of course, there are some stupid interfaces around, which is why I'd like to see a document specifying it].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard says about `peek`:

> Returns: traits::eof() if good() is false.

When the stream's eofbit is set, `good()` will return `false` and therefore `peek` will return `traits::eof()`. This will continue to happen unless you perform an operation that clears the eofbit (such as seeking the stream). It will also return `traits::eof()` if the failbit or badbit are set.

Note: For the default `char`-based streams, `traits::eof()` is the same as `EOF`.